# Crontabing Scrumblr screenshot

Tags: cron, web, screenshot

for a monitoring purpose, once a week, I need to capture some Scrumblr board. So cron will be used.

But how can I get a snapshot/screenshot for an URL ?

This runs on CentOS release 6.3 (Final) without X

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode#Taking_screenshots?

Comment: this could be a good way if I can obtain an upgrade on the installed firefox (currently 10.0.5)

Comment: Firefox provides Linux builds, so that shouldn't be a problem